Laura Ingalls Wilder, By the Shores of Silver Lake: What's the "wonderful story, about dwarfs and caves where robbers lived and a beautiful lady"?
In Laura Ingalls Wilder's By the Shores of Silver Lake, chapter 22, the family get a stash of The New York Ledger magazines. Young Laura discovers a serialized story in the magazine that they all like:

Laura began to read to them all a wonderful story, about dwarfs and caves where robbers lived and a beautiful lady who was lost in the caves.

At first Laura is surprised that the story doesn't finish and is "To be continued"; but she quickly understands the concept and looks through the issues until she finds the end. Then:

Every day she read one more part of the story, and then they wondered until next day what would happen next to the beautiful lady.

We learn nothing more about the story: the date—at least according to the book—would be 1880, but the magazine issues may be older.
Any idea what this story might be? Half snow-white, half gothic novel? The form and genre was popular at the time. I looked at Wikipedia for authors: Emerson Bennett, E. D. E. N. Southworth, Mary Andrews Denison for starters - they wrote scores of novels with dramatic titles about robbers and heiresses and Italy.

Google Books suggested Charles E. Averill's 1847 The Corsair King : https://books.google.com/books?id=vudLAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA92&dq=dwarfs+and+caves+where+robbers+lived+and+a+beautiful+lady+who+was+lost+in+the+caves&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjesNnA7JCIAxXNMVkFHXBdE38Q6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=italy&f=false  Looks suitable gripping, has many of the requisite plot elements. Of course, LIW might not have had a particular story in mind...

Pioneer Girl http://www.pioneergirl.com/blog/archives/6019 found a continued story in the The New York Ledger in 1879: “The Heir of the Castle. A Tale of the Norman Conquest.” I can't find a copy of it though, so I can't say if it contains the required story elements.

Thanks, @kimchi lover, I found that and am enjoying reading it (rabbit hole...), but it doesn't look like the one.

@Clara Díaz Sanchez: Sounds good, but I haven't managed to find a copy either, though it lead me to interesting future reads.

@HerrRau I found it serialised in an Australian newspaper (The Maryorough Gazette) from 1879 - 1880. The story has a very Ivanhoe-vibe. There is a beautiful lady, a dwarf (just one), and caves. The caves are filled with the Saxon resistance, rather than robbers though. Could Laura have mixed up Saxon warriors with robbers? You can find it here: https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/148526703?searchTerm=%22storyteller%22%20AND%20%22heir%22%20AND%20%22normans%22

@ClaraDíazSanchez Good find, thank you! I'll look into it, but will have to take a break - read the 1847 candidate and it left me exhilarated but exhausted.

@kimchilover Maybe I spoke too soon. The Corsair King has, as a flashback, smugglers in caves (with a young girl as a prisoner); it has pirates in caves (with four young women, but only one of them some sort of prisoner, though several have been prisoners before, on shipboard), there is one dwarf that appears regularly in the second half. It definitely reads like a serial, but was published in 1847, maybe too early for a New York Ledger reprint. The story is enchantingly confusing and might have been too scary. I just blogged about it, in German, in too much detail.

It's more than probable that this description, "about dwarfs and caves where robbers lived and a beautiful lady who was lost in the caves", does not apply to a single specific story, but rather to the general type of stories in the New York Ledger which captivated Laura.
Although the Little House... novels by Laura Ingalls Wilder are often regarded as autobiographical, they were heavily edited and somewhat fictionalised, in what Caroline Fraser in Prairie Fires terms “a profound act of American myth-making and self-transformation.” Wilder's letters, unpublished manuscripts, and especially her autobiography Prairie Girl (available for free loan from the Internet Archive) give a more reliable timeline for events. According to Prairie Girl Laura read the back issues of the New York Ledger in the interval between Plum Creek and Silver Lakes. This was an eventful time, in which Ma gave birth to two children (Laura's brother Freddie who died at nine months of age, and Grace), Pa had been left destitute after two successive crops were destroyed by locusts, and Laura helped out by working at the Masters hotel “washing dishes, waiting on tables, and watching 'Little Nan', the baby of Will and Nancy Masters”. None of this is mentioned in the Little House... series. In Prairie Girl, Laura recalls:

When my work was done and Little Nan sleeping, I could curl up in a
corner out of the way and read the stories in the New York Ledger.”
Great stories they were of beautiful ladies and brave, handsome men;
of dwarfs and villians [sic] of jewels and secret caverns. I would
lose myself in them and come to, with a start if Little Nan cried or
Mrs Masters said it was time to set the table for supper.

The description here is very similar to that given in Silver Lakes, with the difference that she is describing the stories in general, rather than one in particular.
To get a flavor of the type of stories the New York Ledger published, the blog Pioneer Girl found that "The Heir of the Castle. A Tale of the Norman Conquest.” was serialized in that journal in 1879. One can repeat Laura's experience of chasing a serial from issue to issue by reading it at the archive of the Maryborough Gazette. The story seems to be somewhat inspired by Ivanhoe, with a beautiful Saxon lady finding sanctuary from the evil Normans in hidden caverns (and a dwarf - though just one - is also present).
